# Powering the Butterfly Labs BFG0005G ASIC Miner

Tags: asic

I got this machine since 2013. I want to put it in use just for the heck of it. It has a USB port for interface with my pc and a power jack. Unfortunately i don't remember where the adaptor is, so how do i power this thing? What volts does it require, is it center positive? Center negative?

I couldn't find any info online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the 5GHs in this picture:

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/30/5e/a0/305ea076f1dac979e04f44cb4de04ed5.jpg

Then the power adapter looks like 12V @ 7.5A. You might even find one on ebay (check the connectors look right in the photos think you want barrel tip)